# Flexdatalist jQuery searchIn specific attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, flexdatalist

Does someone know if with the library flexdatalist jQuery (http://projects.sergiodinislopes.pt/flexdatalist/) for the option searchIn I can specify a custom attribute to search in?

For my dom I have a `<datalist>` where each option has an attribute data-keyword which is several keywords separated by space

```
<option value="exemple1" data-keyword="test example">Example1 </option>
<option value="exemple2" data-keyword="real example">Example2</option>

$('.flexdatalist').flexdatalist({
            minLength: 1,
            selectionRequired: true,
            searchContain: true,
            searchByWord: true,
            searchIn: ["data-keyword","label"],
            noResultsText: 'No result for {keyword}"'
        })
```

So I want to search into the label and attribute data-keyword

Comment: What is `label` in `searchIn: ["data-keyword","label"]` ?

Comment: Hello, it's juste the label of the option (in this case its exemple1 and exemple2)

I found a solution to custom my search with flexdatalist so I will close this topic :)

Answer (score 0):

.on('after:flexdatalist.search', function (event, keyword, data, items)

I am using this event to access the items found by the default search before the display, and then I just add or remove some option of the items array